# Calculating the maximum distance at which the Chain should be kept so that it stays at equilibrium.?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy

[image]

I was solving this problem and came up with this equation which I'm not able to simplify............ $$\mu Sin(\alpha)+Cos(\alpha)=1$$ $where$ $,$ $$0<\mu<1$$ $Solve$ $for$ $"\alpha"$  $?$

Comment: Hello and welcome to the physics stack exchange! Since this is not a typical help site, it would be great to ask questions to benefit the wider audience. You could improve your post by **elaborating your question, explaining where you encounter the problem and what your progress is so far**.

Comment: You can refer to this link for more details : [How to ask homework type questions on this site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).
 In case you find these rules to be a bit harsh, you can always [go to any other suitable sites](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

As someone said before, you can learn the alphabet from these sites and then come back here to ask questions about dinosaurs :)
Have a great time!

Comment: This is a mathematics question, but if you asked it on Math.SE you'd need to show your attempt at solving it. Hint: do you know the formulas for $\sin(A+B)$ & $\cos(A+B)$? Consider why dividing through by $\sqrt{\mu^2+1}$ may be useful.

Comment: Got it ...........Thanks

Comment: Btw I solved it with another way